Alternatives to a Philosophy degree?
I am interested in Mathematics and Philosophy but I am unable to pursue a philosophical education. I would like to not only learn basic philosophy and logic but to also be able to put it on a resume and have it respected. Are there alternative paths-EU based-to a BA in philosophy. For example: Do some Open courses, submit to this or that magazine/journal or something like that. Thanks in advance.

Mensa looks good on a resume.

@ScottRowe A high IQ doesn't really say the same as philosophical education and a bachelors in Maths probably does more for the perception of being intelligent.

@ScottRowe Mensa doesn't look great on a resume, for the most part. Many will see that as egotistical - it's functionally the same as putting your IQ on a resume, which indicates that you happen to be good at logic puzzles, but that doesn't say much about putting that ability to good use. The sum total requirements for joining Mensa is scoring high enough on an IQ test. That said, Mensa does have some nice communities in certain places, with a whole host of "meet-ups" about a variety of topics.

If you want to learn philosophy and logic, you can do courses, watch videos, read books, read research papers. If you want something that's useful for a resume, the only one of those that apply might be courses (online courses don't mean much on a resume, but you may also be able to do a full degree online). Papers in peer-reviewed journals can mean something on a resume. But what's useful on a resume really depends on what you want to use your resume for. A philosophy degree isn't going to count for much for most career paths (although having any degree is required/beneficial for some jobs)

Your resume is not a document which will honestly express your many excellent qualities to a discerning and thoughtful person who desires a coworker or subordinate. Your resume is a pop-up advertisement for convincing a HR worker who will never actually work with you and doesn't know the first thing about what the job you're applying for actually entails, in ten seconds flat, that you will make a good replacement widget.

Whatever difference in time and money you would have spent acquiring a BA in philosophy over just reading what interests you would be much better spent looking at job postings that you think you might want upon completion of your maths degree, noting the phrases used in the Responsibilities section and the statements of company values which you'll generally find buried in there somewhere, and then going out and doing that thing so you can put it on your resume. "Directed and supervised A," "Reviewed and updated procedures for B," "Performed financial risk analysis for C," etc.

@gs Hiring managers and interviewers also look at resumes. The first pass through a resume may just take a few seconds, but if that's successful, it's likely to get a lot more attention, and having a few things on there to demonstrate a range of good qualities is useful. I just don't know that philosophy qualifications would do that, unless you're applying to be a philosophy teacher or something (I could also see it improving the resume of a scientist, perhaps, although a more specialised qualification would probably provide a far greater benefit).

@NotThatGuy I don't see wanting a good job and harmonious friendships as egotistical. Also, bear in mind: "You can't teach 'height'." If someone would reject me for that, it's a timesaver for everyone.
